# SweetAlert position: from fixed to absolute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll, css-position, sweetalert

I need to change the position of my sweet alert box from **fixed** (as the original is) to **absolute**, because the buttons in the bottom are not visible in mobile view (there's a lot of content) and I need to scroll the page.

I tried to change the css but I can't find the right solution.

Is there anyone who has had the same problem?
I hope I was clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a link to the site or a relevant JSfiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.sweet-overlay, .sweet-alert{
    position: absolute!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this question was for an old project, meanwhile I changed digital agency :) but I'll keep it in mind!